# Data export using react-data-table-component export csv

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript, react-data-table-component

I am new to React.

I am trying to export JSON data that is displayed using the 'react-data-table-component' to a CSV file.

I have followed the example from [this link](https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/examples-export-csv--export-csv&globals=backgrounds.grid:false;backgrounds.value:transparent) by copying the exact code snippet provided. Below is my code snippet and the corresponding error occurring during compilation.

```
import Export from "react-data-table-component"
import DataTable, { TableColumn, TableStyles } from "react-data-table-component";
import React from "react";

  ---code declarations---

  const actionsMemo = React.useMemo(() => <Export onExport={() => downloadCSV(customerList)} />, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Row>
        <Col lg={3}>
          <Box className="box" sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
          
            <TextField id="input-with-sx" label="Input National ID" variant="standard" />
            <PersonSearchIcon sx={{ color: 'action.active', mr: 1, my: 0.5 }} />
          </Box>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br/>
      <Row>
        <Col lg={12}>
          <div className="card mb-3">
            <div className="card-body">
              <DataTable columns={columns} data={customerList}
                pagination  customStyles={mycustomStyles} actions={actionsMemo}/>
            </div>
          </div>          
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
```

[image: compilation error]

Could someone help me in identifying any other modules that I may be missing in order to have an export data functionality. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually an import issue.

```
import Export from "react-data-table-component"
```

In this line right here, you are importing **the default export** from the `react-data-table-component` package and assigning it to the variable `Export`.  The default export is the `DataTable` component, which does not have an `onExport` prop.

---

There is no `Export` component exported from the package.  What you are seeing is a locally declared (not exported) `Export` component which is used in their documentation.

```
const Export = ({ onExport }) => <Button onClick={e => onExport(e.target.value)}>Export</Button>;
```

Here's the [source file](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/blob/c247903b8acd260c7204e0a442c3544af3b033ff/stories/DataTable/ExportCSV.stories.js#L51).  It relies on a styled [`Button` component](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/blob/c247903b8acd260c7204e0a442c3544af3b033ff/stories/shared/Button.js).  Their use of `e.target.value` here does not make any sense to me.

---

You can create your own `Export` component with proper TypeScript types by putting either of these in your code:

Simple version:

```
export const Export = ({ onExport }: { onExport: () => void }) => (
  <button onClick={() => onExport()}>Export</button>
);
```

With support for any props of the HTML `button` (such as `className` and `style`):

```
type ExportProps = {
  onExport: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"];

export const Export = ({ onExport, ...props }: ExportProps) => (
  <button {...props} onClick={onExport}>
    Export
  </button>
);
```

Comment: Thanks to this I've been able to solve it by creating my own `Export` component as suggested.

Comment: The source code for the example (bringing a bit more context to the code in the example) can be found here: [link](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/blob/master/stories/DataTable/ExportCSV.stories.js)

Answer (score 2):

I have very simple solution for this issue.

You can try to convert table data json to csv or xlsx with very simple methods.

My sample code is try to convert json to xlsx:

```
  function downloadXLS() {
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.myJsonDataArray);
    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "People");
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'reports.xlsx');
  }
```

Add button to download:

```
<Button onClick={() => downloadXLS()}>Export</Button>
```

Another solution is data array to csv: (I got this code from previous response)

```
function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(array) {
    let result;

    const columnDelimiter = ',';
    const lineDelimiter = '\n';
    const keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

    result = '';
    result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
    result += lineDelimiter;

    array.forEach(item => {
        let ctr = 0;
        keys.forEach(key => {
            if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

            result += item[key];
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
            ctr++;
        });
        result += lineDelimiter;
    });

    return result;
}


function downloadCSV() {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    let csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(this.myJsonDataArray);
    if (csv == null) return;

    const filename = 'export.csv';

    if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
        csv = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${csv}`;
    }

    link.setAttribute('href', encodeURI(csv));
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.click();
}
```

Add button to download:

```
<Button onClick={() => downloadCSV()}>Export</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based from Bilal Demir, this is my solution for React + react-data-table-component:

First install:

```
    npm install xlsx
```

Excel.tsx

```
import { utils, writeFileXLSX } from 'xlsx';
export const handleDownloadExcel = (dataSource:any,sheetName:string,fileName:string) => {
        const ws = utils.json_to_sheet(dataSource);
        const wb = utils.book_new();
        utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, sheetName);
        writeFileXLSX(wb, `${fileName}.xlsx`);        
    };
```

In Table View, react-bootstrap + react-data-table-component:

```
    import { handleDownloadExcel } from "../../../components/Excel";

    const downloadExcel = () => {
        handleDownloadExcel(dataSource,"SHEET_NAME","MY_FILENAME")  
    };
 

    <Container fluid className="form-group row mt-10">

    <Col>
        <Button type={'button'} className="btn-sm float-end mx-2" text="Excel" onClick={downloadExcel}  />           
        <DataTable
            columns={columns}
            data={dataSource}
            pagination               
            
        />
    </Col>
</Container>
```